# How to access state inside constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access a state value inside the constructor more than one place.
When I console.log(this) inside the constructor, I can see that it is possible to access a specific value, however when I console.log this.state, I get undefined.

This is how I imagined it could work (I want to access the state in CSSValue):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    colors: {
      SheetColor: "#FFFFFF"
    },
    CSSValue: '.qvt-sheet{\n background:' + $(this.state.colors.SheetColor) + '!important;\n}'
  }
}
```

However when I run this code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    colors: {
      SheetColor: "#FFFFFF"
    },
    CSSValue: '.qvt-sheet{\n background:' + $(console.log(this)) + '!important;\n}'
  }
}
```

then I get this in the console:

[image]

But when I change the console.log to console.log(this.state) it prints undefined.

I can access e.g. this.props without any problems. But somehow I cannot acces this.state in console.log.

Comment: Why do you have a '$' sign in the string? what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot read state in the constructor. And even if you could, your usage would not work. You are assigning to state an object literal expression. Inside this expression you use `this.state` to reference a color that you are setting in said object literal expression. This kind of circular referencing is not possible, because the entire expression has to be evaluated before being assigned to `this.state`.

The reason you can see `state` when you `console.log(this)` is because you log a *reference* to the component. Once state has been set on the component, it will be shown in DevTools. When you `console.log(this.state)`, `this.state` is `undefined` at this point in time, and you will therefore log out `undefined` and not a reference to the state object.

And another point: You are mixing regular strings and template literal syntax. You should do:

```js
`.qvt-sheet{\n background: ${this.state.colors.SheetColor} !important;\n}`
```